# DOM create object direct from his HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

in my project i have stored in a variable (htmlG) an html code like this:

```
<img src="http://mygrtew.imm.com/graph?&o=f&c=1&y=q&b=ffffff&n=666666&w=450&h=250&r=1m&u=www.test.com" width="450" height="250"/>
```

and i would like to insert dinamically in a div that i create with DOM  this image directly

```
var htmlG = response.testg;
    var divAgraph = createElement('div', 'divAgraph', 'divAgraphcss');
    var oImgG = createElement('img');
    oImgG.setAttribute('src',htmlG);
    divAgraph.appendChild(oImgG);
```

but fail, probably because in var htmlG at the beginning there is  correct?

How can icreate my img with these parameters?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the `createElement` function?

Comment: `var htmlG = "<img src="http://mygrtew.imm.com/graph?&o=f&c=1&y=q&b=ffffff&n=666666&w=450&h=250&r=1m&u=www.test.com" width="450" height="250"/>"` Is it like this you assigned??

Comment: @lonesomeday he is probably referring to a wrapper of [the method defined in document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).

Comment: @JackieXu Presumably so, but it would be nice to have that confirmed, since he isn't using the normal signature of that method.

Comment: yes is my method like this:

Comment: function createElement(tagName, id, className) {
    var elm = document.createElement(tagName);
    if (id) {
        elm.id = id;
    }
    if (className) {
        elm.className = className;
    }
    return elm;
}

Comment: If your question was unclear please edit it to provide all information needed to fully understand and follow it. Readers should not have to read (all) the comments as well.

Comment: Probabli i think that i have to grab only code contained between <img src=" and "> from my variable and pass it at the oImgG2.setAttribute('src' , but how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
var htmlG = response.testg;
var divAgraph = document.createElement('div');
divAgraph.innerHTML = htmlG
```

I assume you are working in an environment that provides DOM. (node.js does not)

Answer (score 1):

You try to **set** the `src` **attribute** of your `<img>` element

```
oImgG.setAttribute('src',htmlG);
```

yet htmlG does not contain the src attribute content but a complete HTML img element as well.

So instead of your current

```
var htmlG = '<img src="http://mygrtew.imm.com/graph?&o=f&c=1&y=q&b=ffffff&n=666666&w=450&h=250&r=1m&u=www.test.com" width="450" height="250"/>';
oImgG.setAttribute('src', htmlG);
```

you probably want to

```
var htmlG = 'http://mygrtew.imm.com/graph?&o=f&c=1&y=q&b=ffffff&n=666666&w=450&h=250&r=1m&u=www.test.com';
oImgG.setAttribute('src', htmlG);
```

If you want to set the width and height attributes as well, you will have to call [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.setAttribute) for those two separately.

---

If you have to work with the **entire HTML code for the element** - as the dereferencing of `response.testg` suggests, you can use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) to set the content of your div - and not call `setAttribute` at all.

```
divAgraph.innerHTML = htmlG
```